# How to portably determine capability of interactive device to generate characters from the basic source character set

Tags: c, keyboard, character, stdin, portability

I would like to write a portable program in which user's input device (e.g., a keyboard) is connected to `stdin`. I want a way to compute whether the input device in combination with the program is capable of causing characters from the basic source character set (N2176, Section 5.2.1) to appear in the `stdin` stream.

In the code

```
// ...
int c = fgetc ( stdin ) ;
if ( c == 'A' )
{
    MAYBE: launchMissles () ;
}
// ...
```

for example, I would want to be sure that it is possible for the statement labeled `MAYBE` to be reached.

I think if I were able to know the encoding of `stdin`, that would suffice. So, is there a portable way to detect the encoding associated with `srdin`?

Here is a suboptimal solution:

```
puts("Please enter the following characters:");
puts( // graphic characters from the basic source character set
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    "0123456789"
    "!\"#%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?[\\]^_{|}~") ;
// etc. ...
```

A technique similar to this is/was used in Lego Star Wars (among other games) to allow the user to customize the controls. The user would press the button (on a game controller) or key (on the keyboard) that corresponds to "jump," and so forth.

Comment: If you want to annoy users ask them to enter 100 chars in a particular order. It makes no sense.

Comment: @0___________: yeah, like I said, _suboptimal_. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: It is not *suboptimal* - it simply makes no sense at all.

Comment: @0___________: so, asking the user for input as a means of collecting information on what input is possible makes _no_ sense? I agree it's awkward. I am looking for something better. If I had nice solution, I probably would not have written the question in the first place.

Comment: Why do you want it? Games do not use `stdin`

Comment: @0___________: If the input device cannot possibly produce the range of characters needed by the program, the program will exit. And, yes, some games do use stdin, e.g., [Zork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zork), [Trade Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_Wars).